# Can't submit form with javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

To keep it short and simple... I have an ajax call that doesn't seem to submit my form. My form is made from javascript functions etc. I don't know if this would actually influence the ajax submit or not.

Ajax call:

```
function saveExercise() {
 // more not related code

$('.eBlock').each(function (i, contents) {
//some code thats inside this function but not related
});

 $.ajax({
    url: 'saveJson.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: eBlock,
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (response) {
    window.location = 'index.php';
  });
 }
}
```

my html:

```
<form  id='my_form' class="container-fluid" action="" method="POST">
       <button id='resetInputs' type='button' onclick='getResetInputs()' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-refresh fa-2x resetInputs'></button>
       <button type='button' id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

all my related javascript: (containing the eBlock)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
  'class': 'btn btn-success',
 'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
   $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
   $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select();
   id++;
   exerciseAudioInput++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

  $('form').append(addOpdracht);
  $('form').append(getExerciseTitle());
});


 function getExerciseBlock(i){
   var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
  'id': i,
  'class': 'col-md-12 eBlock'
  });

   $(eBlock).append(getRemoveBtnExercise(i), getAudioBtn(i), 
   getWordInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), 
   getRemoveBtn(i), getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

   return eBlock;
   }
```

I don't seem to have any errors besides one that isn't even related to this problem. In case you're wondering what the error is: It's an internal error related to audio, so no worries.
I have done some research and made some little changes such as the "Submit" changed to "button" etc. but nothing big came out of it.

Cheers!

Comment: where is your ajax call function

Comment: I'm seeing a local `eBlock` which is a jQuery `div`. I don't see how it would end up being accessible inside your ajax call, let alone contain form data.

Comment: It's possible you can fix this with a single small change: `data: $('#my_form').serialize(),`

Comment: @ChrisG you are most likely right since I am a total newbie with ajax, I thought this contained data since everything is being appended to my eBlock.